# basic theory: adaboost classifier in scikit

Tags: python, adaboost

my understanding is that AdaBoostClassifier uses a collection of different classifiers to train data, and outputs a meta classifier that's composed of the differently weighted classifiers that gives highest accuracy. I see in scikit 's page on adaboost there's base_estimator parameter, does this only choose the first/starting classifier? does the n_estimator parameter pick how many classifiers adaboost will try before ending? if so how does it know which of the say n=10 classifiers to pick when I call the function?

is there a complete list of classifiers AdaBoost uses?